# How do i correctly convert a integer back to Bitmap

Tags: android, android-studio, image-processing

In Android Studio I can use the following lines of code to get an array from Bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = get_Image();
Bitmap resizeBitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap);

int[] iArr = new int[(resizeBitmap.getWidth() * resizeBitmap.getHeight())];
resizeBitmap.getPixels(iArr, 0, resizeBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, resizeBitmap.getWidth(), resizeBitmap.getHeight());
```

Here is the resizer function:

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (576 == bitmap.getWidth() && 1024 == bitmap.getHeight()) {
        return bitmap;
    }

    Bitmap createBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(576, 1024, Config.RGB_565);

    Matrix scaledMatrix = scaledMatrix(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), createBitmap.getWidth(), createBitmap.getHeight());
    new Canvas(createBitmap).drawBitmap(bitmap, scaledMatrix, null);
    return createBitmap;
}
```

However when I convert that int array back to bitmap the image is wrong

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(1024, 576, Config.RGB_565);
bmp.setPixels(iArr, 0, 1024, 0, 0, 1024, 576);
textViewToChange.setText("Bitmap created");
```

This is the image when i save it to a file or display it https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPEwl.jpg The above image is how it looks like and below is how it should had looked like

If i read the incorrect image in python, the RGB pixels are placed exactly where they should be like in the correct image but the image dosen't look the same. Why? How can i fix this?

Comment: That's the weirdest way of resizing a bitmap I've ever seen.  Use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap instead

Comment: You're switching between ARGB and RGB_565 encoding somewhere.  That's what images look like when  you do that, you can see a pattern as earch row becomes 2 or 3 shrunken rows

Comment: Also i realized my width and height are wrong in the last snippet. I placed them opposite